# sql SERVER - distinct selection based on priority columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

hello I would like to find a solution to solve my problem in a single request if possible.
For the moment I take all the records then I go through the lines one by one to eliminate what I don't want.

I have 2 tables : first table with links

[image]

the second with the prefered label for the url

[image]

the second table must be consulted keeping only the row with maximum priority

priority rules are
the current user then
the user group and finally
everyone.

if the hidden column is true, exclude any reference to the url

here is the expected result.

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't see any other solution than to multiply the conditions on several selects and unions.

if you have a idea to solve my problem, thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Next time, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste the table data as formatted text into your request instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution but i think there is better to do.

in the condition's select, I built a column which gives a level note according to the priorities

```
DECLARE @CUR_USER VARCHAR(10) =  'ROBERT'
DECLARE @CUR_GROUP VARCHAR(10) =  'DEV'

DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE (
    URL_ID INT
    ,URLNAME VARCHAR(100)
    );


DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE (
    PREF_ID INT
    ,URL_ID INT
    ,FAVORITE_LABEL VARCHAR(100)
    ,USER_GROUP VARCHAR(10)
    ,USER_CODE VARCHAR(10)
    ,HIDE_URL DECIMAL(1, 0) DEFAULT 0
    );

    INSERT INTO @TABLE1
VALUES
(1, 'https://stackoverflow.com/')
,(2,    'https://www.microsoft.com/')
,(3,    'https://www.apple.com/')
,(4,    'https://www.wikipedia.org/')
;

INSERT INTO @TABLE2 
VALUES 
(1000, 1, 'find everything', NULL, 'ROBERT', 0)
,(1001, 1, 'a question ? find the answer here', 'DEV', NULL, 0)
,(1002, 1, 'StackOverFlow', NULL, NULL, 0)
,(1003, 2, 'Windows', 'DEV', NULL, 0)
,(1004, 2, 'Microsoft', NULL, NULL, 0)
,(1005, 3, 'Apple', NULL, NULL, 0)
,(1006, 4, 'Free encyclopedia', NULL, 'ROBERT', 1)
,(1007, 4, 'Wikipedia', NULL, NULL, 0)
,(1008, 1, 'StackOverFlow FOR MAT', 'MAT', NULL, 0)
,(1009, 2, 'Microsoft FOR MAT', 'MAT', NULL, 0)
,(1010, 3, 'Apple', 'MAT', NULL, 1)
,(1011, 4, 'Wikipedia FOR MAT', 'MAT', NULL, 0)
,(1012, 1, 'StackOverFlow', NULL, 'JEAN', 1)
,(1013, 2, 'Microsoft ', NULL, 'JEAN', 0)
,(1014, 3, 'Apple', NULL, 'JEAN', 0)
,(1015, 4, 'great encyclopedia', NULL, 'JEAN', 0)
;

SELECT t2.* ,t1.URLName
FROM @TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN @TABLE2 t2 ON t1.URL_ID = t2.URL_ID
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP (1) test.PREF_ID
                ,CASE 
                    -- if I do not comment  this case: jean from the MAT group will not see apple
                    -- WHEN Hide_Url = 1
                    --  THEN 3
                    WHEN USER_code IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 2
                    WHEN USER_GROUP IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END AS ROW_LEVEL
            FROM @TABLE2 test
            WHERE (
                    (
                        test.USER_GROUP IS NULL
                        AND test.user_group IS NULL
                        AND test.USER_code IS NULL
                        )
                    OR (test.USER_GROUP = @CUR_GROUP)
                    OR (test.USER_code = @CUR_USER)
                    )
                AND t2.URL_ID = test.URL_ID
            ORDER BY ROW_LEVEL DESC
            ) test
        WHERE test.PREF_ID = t2.PREF_ID
            AND Hide_Url = 0
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you can rely on `pref_id` for the preference ordering, correct?  If so, you could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.url_id = table1.url_id
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY table1.url
    ORDER BY pref_id ASC
) = 1
```

This will partition by the url and then provide only the one with lowest pref_id.

I didn't test this SQL as I wasn't sure which RDBMS you're running on, but I used [Rasgo](https://docs.rasgoml.com/rasgo-docs/transforms/all-transforms) to translate the SQL.

Comment: no sorry I can't. I gave these example tables to explain my need. in the real schema i have guids and other tables

Answer (score 0):

maybe of interest in this tricky query:

```
select so.*, table1.url from 
(select distinct t.url_id, 
  (select pref_id from table2 s where s.url_id = t.url_id order by "user" is null, "group" is null limit 1) pref_id
  from table2 t
  where not exists(select 1 from table2 s where s.hide and s.url_id = t.url_id)
) ids
join table2 so on so.pref_id = ids.pref_id
join table1 ON table1.url_id = ids.url_id
order by so.url_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an `ORDER BY` clause that puts the preferred row first. You can use this in the window function `ROW_NUMBER` and work with this or use a lateral top(1) join with `CROSS APPLY`.

```
select *
from urls
cross apply
(
  select top(1) *
  from labels
  where labels.url_id = urls.url_id
  where [Group] is not null or [user] is not null or hide is not null
  order by
    case when [Group] is null then 2 else 1 end,
    case when [user] is null then 2 else 1 end,
    case when hide is null then 2 else 1 end
) top_labels
order by urls.url_id;
```